# Sails js ORM isssue

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

I've been facing this issue 3 days

- node v 14.15.1
- sails v  1.5.2

[image]

I have upgraded and downgraded nodeJs version and sails js version also downgraded sail-mongo

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not a screenshot.